# Compile Rust program for raspberry pi `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` from 64 bit arch linux

Tags: linux, rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

I want to compile a Rust program from my laptop for my raspberry pi. I am having issues upgrading the version of C on the pi and cannot install rust to compile it from there.

I followed [this](https://hackernoon.com/compiling-rust-for-the-raspberry-pi-49fdcd7df658) tutorial for cross compiling rust for rpi. I can compile simple programs this way with no problems, however the program I want to compile uses sqlite and openssl and this is where I am having issues.

I have installed `lib32-dbus`, `lib32-openssl` and `lib32-sqlite`. Doing `export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib32` and `export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl-1.0` fixes openssl, but the linker still can't find the 32 bit version of the sqlite lib and exits with this error:

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1 cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

...

note: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
```

Full error [here](https://pastebin.com/Xa40CJw1).

Is there some sort of `SQLITE_LIB_DIR` env variable that I can set? If not, how do I point the linker to the correct version? Thanks.

Edit: I have now downloaded and cross compiled libsqlite3 for arm linux. Now I just need to know how to point the linker to the arm version.

Comment: You are linking against your local libsqlite. You have either cross compiler libsqlite3 yourself or use a precompiled one.

Comment: Once I have cross compiled it, how do I point the linker to it?

Comment: *"how do I point the linker to it..."* - In C you typically use `--sysroot`. The C compiler will invoke the linker for you. The `sysroot` has all the headers and libraries needed for the target. I understand Rust reinvented the wheel. There's no telling how to do the same in Rust. When I tried to build a new Firefox Geckodriver for ARM Rust and Cargo broke the build. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cross-compile your Rust program with every feature of OpenSSL, because some versions of OpenSSL don't support (feature as Vendored) which helps for cross-compilation. So you can use a version of OpenSSL which supports this feature, like `openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }`